# Unable to test Lightweight-Charts in React app

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, lightweight-charts

In my Create React App when importing the lightweight-chars like so everything's working:

```
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';
```

However, when running tests with:

```
yarn test --all
```

this error is shown:

● Test suite failed to run

```
.../node_modules/lightweight-charts/dist/lightweight-charts.esm.development.js:7
import { bindToDevicePixelRatio } from 'fancy-canvas/coordinate-space';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  ...
```

Please suggest if looks familiar.

Answer (score 2):

Currently it's impossible to use/import `lightweight-charts` in nodejs context. You can subscribe on https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/488 to be notified when it'll be solved.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the perfect solution to fix the root cause, but I was able to fix the errors via `jest` option in `package.json`.

```
...
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(lightweight-charts|fancy-canvas)/)"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2537#issuecomment-390341713) is the only thing that worked for me:

```
npm test -- --transformIgnorePatterns "node_modules/(?!(lightweight-charts|fancy-canvas)/)"
```

This worked for me because I have an unejected create react app project and therefore `transformIgnorePatterns` is not available via `jest.config.js` or the `package.json`.